# jersey web service method not recognized as valid resource method

Tags: web-services, jersey

I have a web service whose method looks like

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getString(@QueryParam("path") path) {
    return "got the string " + path
}
```

When I run this I get an error message

```
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public java.lang.String com.example.getString(java.lang.Object) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Method, public java.lang.String com.example.getString(java.lang.Object), annotated with GET of resource, class com.example.MyServiceClass, is not recognized as valid resource method.
```

What does this error message mean? If I run the service without a param, then it works.

Comment: Do you have the `@Path` annotation in place?

Comment: I have `@Path` on the class as a whole. Do I need it on the individual method as well if there is only one `@GET` method in the service?

Comment: Can you tell what is the @Path that you are using. Ensure that the @Path("/url/{path}") is of this form.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question...

I am using groovy and I forgot the type of the @QueryParam. That appears to be needed.